# Does oracle undo sequence increase after transaction rollback?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, sequence

I have a Spring application with Hibernate as ORM & Oracle database as RDBMS. Assume my table name in the database is `entity_tbl` and `entity_seq` is the sequence of my table.

In the save method with `@Transaction`, the entity was save and after saving the line, I throw an exception for rollback transaction. like below,

```
@Service
class EntityService extends GenericService<Entity>{

    @Autowired
    EntityRepository repo;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void save(Entity entity) {
       repo.save(entity);
       if(true)
           throw ApplicationException("just for Transaction rollback...")
    }
}
```

In application console I see this line:

```
select entity_seq.nextval from dual
```

If I run this query on PL/SQL, the `entity_seq` was increased and `entity_seq.currval` had a new value. But after transaction rollback in above code `entity_seq.currval` has past value and not increased.

So my question is: Does Oracle decrease sequence after transaction rollback? or oracle's temp table undo this increase? or Hibernate manage it? in other words, my question is why sequence after when I see `select entity_seq.nextval from dual` in application console was unchanged?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure if your observation is correct, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104407/oracle-sequence-transactionality) and many other Oracle doesn't rollback sequence value. Are you sure the value was decreased?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle Sequence Transactionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104407/oracle-sequence-transactionality)

Comment: @karol-dowbecki my question is why sequence after `nextval` was unchanged?

Comment: @MortezaAsadi the problem is that common knowledge is that sequence are not rolled back. Are you sure that `select entity_seq.nextval from dual` was actually executed in the database?  For example it could be identifier caching in Hibernate, the ids are loaded in bulk to avoid getting sequence value on every insert.

Comment: @karol-dowbecki I'm not sure this query was actually executed in the database, But it logged in my application console, like other `select/insert/delete/update` queries.  in fact I expect that like other logged queries this one also would executed in the database.

Answer (score 1):

> But after transaction rollback in above code entity_seq.currval has past value and not increased.

`currval` never increases the sequence it contains the last assigned value independent of the `ROLLBACK`.

Check in *pure* DB without the `ORM` stuff.

```
SQL> insert into tab(x)
  2  select seq.nextval from dual;

1 row created.

SQL> insert into tab(x)
  2  select seq.nextval from dual;

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> select * from tab;

         X
----------
         1
         2

SQL>
SQL> select seq.currval from dual;

   CURRVAL
----------
         2

SQL>
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL>
SQL> select * from tab;

no rows selected

SQL>
SQL> select seq.currval from dual;

   CURRVAL
----------
         2

SQL>
```

You see the last assigned value (2) is returned from the `currval`. Check for some caching effects if you see other results.